# is there code smell in this usage of let

Tags: clojure

I often end up in code like this in let where I am creating temporary variables just to hold state. What is a better way to do it?

The thrush operator will not help because though e is temporary, I still need c and d in the consecutive let forms.

```
(let [[c d] (sum [a b])
      e     (if (even? c) c 0)
      f     (+ s e)]
   .....
  )
```

Comment: It smells like it's not valid clojure ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of ways you could reorganize it. I don't think either is objectively better than what you wrote though, but I will post it as food for thought.

```
(let [c (first (sum [a b]))
      f (+ s (if (even? c) c 0))]
  ...)
```

Or this

```
(defn evenz [n]
  (if (even? n) n 0))

(let [f (+ s (evenz (first (sum [a b]))))]
  ...)
```

Answer (score 3):

This looks fine to me. The "state" is not really a state - there are no side-effects involved. It might become bad if there's a lot of bindings in the `let` and their dependencies become hard to trace but that's the general property of complicated code (duh), not specific to this pattern.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any problem with this pattern. You will need to create the temporary vars in this case because the various operations are not directly composable and hence you use temp vars to make them work.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like fairly clear "functional style" code from my perspective. I see nothing wrong with it except for the names are a bit short ;-)

- giving everything a name with let may make the code bigger, though easier to learn
- using conditionals in lets is common even in the clojure source
- the formatting is normal for let statements.

perhaps more context would lead to constructive suggestions?